# window onload javascript in chrome

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance.

Please find the following script, it alerts e.value = "yes" in fire fox and "no" chrome...
what' wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />        
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>new_file</title>                 
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            function func(){                
                alert("I am at Func")
            }

            var i = 0;
            document.write("<form style='display: block'><input name='test' id='test' value='no'></form>");

            window.onload = function () {
                global();   
            };

            function global(){
                var e=document.getElementById("test");
                alert(e.value);
                if(e.value=="no" && i == 0 ){
                    e.value="yes";                      
                    i = 1;              
                }
                else {
                    //e.value="no";                 
                    func(); 
                }
            }                               
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

What i need is based on that e.value i need to call the func()? Any one please answer it...

Comment: Why you use document.write? Totally unnecessary here. Just include the form as normal html.

Comment: Try using if(e.value === "no" && i === 0 ){

Comment: for a start, in function func, alert("iam at func") should have a semi-colon after it

Comment: There's all sorts wrong with this code. `e.value="yes"` and `document.getElementById("test").value = t;` are effectively doing the same thing. You can remove `var t = e.value; document.getElementById("test").value = t;`.

Comment: @imulsion [Semicolons are optional](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) in JS, though it is good practice to include them for various reasons.

Comment: Hi flem, thanks for your reply... e.value="yes" and document.getElementById("test").value = t; both are the same thing...but for testing purpose only i put that...Thank you once again for your comment.

Comment: Is this kinda test question or what? Your code works as expected. In every browser it alerts `no`, and never invokes `func()`. If you're reusing it, probably you've forgotten to set `i = 0` before invoke `global()` again.